# ContextMenu для RecyclerView

Tags: recyclerview, android-context-menu

Уже неделю пытаюсь сделать контекстное меню для RecyclerView. Переписал код с ListView на RecyclerView с CardView и вот теперь какие инструкции не пробовал, но контекстное меню так и не работает. Думаю проблема в самом RecyclerView и холдере.
Выложу весь код класса, пожалуйста, у кого есть время, осмотрите и выскажите свои предположения. Прокрутка с cardview работает!

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>  {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;



    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, View.OnClickListener,
            MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener{
        public TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item);
            v.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG,"onClick");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            MenuItem myActionItem = menu.add("Some menu item");
            myActionItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Select The Action");
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Call");//groupId, itemId, order, title
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "SMS");
            Log.d(TAG,"onCreate");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Log.d(TAG,"ItemClick");
            return false;
        }
    }


    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> dataset) {
        mDataset = dataset;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onClick ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Конечно я вам очень поздно отвечаю :P но...:

```
MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);
                popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_my_menu);
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(ViewHolder.this);
                popup.show();
            }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Лучше позже, чем никогда :D